# C# WPF app is running each time on windows startup after installation

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield

I have created a small app that is build with C# and wpf.

I have created an installer with "installshield limited edition for visual studio 2013" and installed it.

Now every time when my windows is running app is running too,but I did not foudn any setting where I can disable it,  does anybody now how I can disable it grammatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many ways an Application can opt to start up every time the windows starts.

The first way is to register itself in Windows Registry .

you should check the following paths for any Registry entry that causes the app to startup with windows :

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

For more information about using Registry keys to get apps to startup with windows , refer to [Run and RunOnce Registry Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx).

The second way it is to put a shortcut for the app in the "Start Up" folder.

Since Windows 8   , Start up folder is no longer exist in the start menu .

If you need to find the start up folder on windows 8 or a greater version of windows , [refer to this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2806079).

It is sufficient to delete the registry key , or the start up shortcut for an app to  get windows to stop running it every time it starts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, probably I should have some shortcuts in wrong place.i will check it.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks,you was right, I have an shortcut in startup folder.